# Plan cannot run because you have reached your concurrent build limit

Tags: bamboo

Getting this error in Bamboo when I hover over the Run option . Run is disabled.

Comment: Do you have this plan in progress? If no, does Run option is enabled when you refresh page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This basically means that you're already running the same project in Bamboo.  For each project, only one 'instance' can be running at a time.

This behavior can be adjusted by going under the Administration, to Concurrent Builds.  It requires you to have both enabled Concurrent Builds, and have multiple agents capable of running that build.

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, check the remote agent status. I had this error when "somehow" the automatic Windows service running the remote agent on a server had been stopped...

Answer (score 2):

I had dedicated the agent to perform the same job twice, that is why I was not able to run that. 
1) Go to Settings on the top menu.
2) Click Overview
3) Click on Concurrent Build in the left panel.
4) Select no of builds and save

I remove one of two same jobs dedicated to agent for the same build and I am able to run.